# why using PyQt5 on mac can not add a icon?

Tags: python, macos, python-3.x, pyqt5

```
import sys
import os
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QWidget
from PyQt5.QtGui import QIcon

class Example(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.initUI()

    def initUI(self):
        self.setGeometry(300,300,300,220)
        self.setWindowTitle('Icon')

        path = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(sys.modules[__name__].__file__), 'icon_1.png')
        self.setWindowIcon(QIcon(path))

        self.show()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    ex = Example()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

I also use a relative path like
`self.setWindowIcon(QIcon('icon_1.png'))`
I am sure icon_1.png is at the directory.But the result is always like that:

[image: with no icon in the window and Dock]

So where did I make some wrong? I am a newbie in both PyQt and StackOverflow and English... Hope the post is valid.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Do you get any error message?

Comment: @Irnzcig no, I use eclipse+pydev, the program runs without any error or warning (the console is quite blank)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

`setWindowIcon` is a method for `QApplication`, not for `QWidget` and friends

Here is a working version of your test script:

```
import sys
import os
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QWidget
from PyQt5.QtGui import QIcon

class Example(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super(Example, self).__init__()
        self.initUI()

    def initUI(self):
        self.setGeometry(300,300,300,220)
        self.setWindowTitle('Icon')
        self.show()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    path = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(sys.modules[__name__].__file__), 'icon_1.png')
    app.setWindowIcon(QIcon(path))
    ex = Example()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: For the icon display on desktop for example, there is a platform dependant technique explained [here](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/appicon.html).

Comment: Thank you! You are right and the problem is settled. I follow a tutorial but seems that it also has some mistakes, I should also read the document.

Answer (score 1):

Try using `QPixmap('myLogo.png')` inside the `QIcon()` call. Have just tried this on Mac and is working for me =].